# How to you get an AWS client-token to use with `aws ec2 run-instances`?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

As described here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-ec2-feature-idempotent-instance-creation/ AWS CLI enforces idempotency of the `aws ec2 run-instances --cli-input-json` command. Unfortunately there is no documentation on how a client-token is generated.

I did find that there is a `ClientToken` field in the `aws ec2 describe-instances` results, but of course you still get the following error if you try to use one:

```
An error occurred (IdempotentParameterMismatch) when calling the RunInstances operation: Arguments on this idempotent request are inconsistent with arguments used in previous request(s).
```

How do I get a token to use with [`--client-token`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/Run_Instance_Idempotency.html#Run_Instance_Idempotency_CLI)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You make one up!

Putting any string < 64 chars will work. The describe call simply gives you back the client-token string used to create the instance

The idea then is then you handle failures like this.

1. Generate the client Token i.e. "Bobs instance"
2. Make successful run instance call with client-token
3. Something goes wrong on the client i.e.  Script fails or times out
4. Your code starts again and generates the same client token( the trick is making sure this happens)
5. You get an a success but you actually get back the same response with same reservation-Id  you got the first time you made the request and no second instance is created

I suggest reading http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/Run_Instance_Idempotency.html for more info on idempotency.

It's been ages since I coded this but I believe when I did it I had my workers use the SQS message ID as the client-token, so if my workers failed, or sqs delivered twice, I wouldn't leak instances.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer what must have seemed like a stupid question. It's funny that I tried every client token I could find in my logs and none of them worked... because they were in my logs as a result of having been used. The only string I tried that wasn't a logged client token was an `aws sts get-session-token` which failed because it was greater than 64 characters. Ugh!

Comment: My new solution to this is `aws ec2 run-instances --cli-input-json file://spec.json --client-token "$(TZ=UTC date)"` which works great. However, I caution you not to do this in an unmonitored process. Idempotency is there for your protection. It's one thing to bypass it like this when you are mentally engaged at the CLI. Use caution doing so in automation.

Comment: You can  also just remove the --client-token  parameter from the command, its optional.

Comment: It's optional until it's required. It's required after you've run the command once. The requirement is there to prevent accidental rerunning of commands. When you are spinning up a cluster of Kubernetes servers, or something similar, it makes sense to want to launch 8 identical instances. But, you have to use `--client-token` to indicate you realize what you are doing.